# Keep track of item's versions after new insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, pyodbc

I'm currently working on creating a Log Table that will have all the data from another table and will also have recorded, as Versions, changes in the prices of items in the main table.

I would like to know how it is possible to save the versions, that is, increment the value +1 at each insertion of the same item in the Log table.

The Log table is loaded via a Merge of data coming from the User API, on a python script using PYODBC:

```
MERGE LogTable as t
USING (Values(?,?,?,?,?)) AS s(ID, ItemPrice, ItemName)
ON t.ID = s.ID AND t.ItemPrice= s.ItemPrice 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (ID, ItemPrice, ItemName, Date)
VALUES (s.ID, s.ItemPrice, s.ItemName, GETDATE())
```

Table example:

| Id | ItemPrice | ItemName | Version | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | Foo | 1 | Today |
| 2 | 30 | bar | 1 | Today |

And after inserting the Item with ID = 1 again with a different price, the table should look like this:

| Id | ItemPrice | ItemName | Version | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | Foo | 1 | Today |
| 2 | 30 | bar | 1 | Today |
| 1 | 45 | Foo | 2 | Today |

Saw some similar questions mentioning using triggers but in these other cases it was not a Merge used to insert the data into the Log table.

Comment: Wouldn't a temporal table make more sense?

Comment: I recommended recording only the dates when the items were inserted in the Log table, which would be a good way to have the change history. But I was asked these 'Versions' which is basically a counter of how many duplicate IDs there are . I'll search about the temporal tables and see if it fits too, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Obligatory reference to warning about using merge: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. Definitely a good read, didn't know about those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May the following helps you, modify your insert statement as this:

```
Insert Into tbl_name
Values (1, 45, 'Foo', 
COALESCE((Select MAX(D.Version) From tbl_name D Where D.Id = 1), 0) + 1, GETDATE())
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22dff1f7bc6e6b4a58ea79f16a0dc9e0).

**Update**, according to the proposed enhancements by @GarethD:

First: Using `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE` will be more performant.

> Where performance can play an important role is when the result is not a constant, but rather a query of some sort. [-1-](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)

Second: prevent race condition that may occur when multiple threads trying to read the `MAX` value. So the query will be as the following:

```
Insert Into tbl_name WITH (HOLDLOCK)
Values (1, 45, 'Foo', 
ISNULL((Select MAX(D.Version) From tbl_name D Where D.Id = 1), 0) + 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Since I'm already using a Merge statement on a Python script I don't know how to use this insert statement. I'll try it out!

Comment: Just an update, I was able to insert using COALESCE and so far it is working fine. I'll need to test for other scenarios as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For SQL Server you should use `ISNULL` rather than `COALESCE` here - Since `COALESCE` expands to a case expression internally the subquery ends up being executed twice. On this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=734d6b6ac9e95eb06eda4b1052bf6903) note the extra reference to `tbl_name` in the plan with coalesce compared to isnull. You're also going to want to use `HOLDLOCK` (e.g. INSERT INTO tbl_name WITH (HOLDLOCK)...` to prevent a race condition.

Comment: @GarethD, Thank you for this great feedback, do you mind if I update the answer according to your proposed enhancements?

Comment: No problem at all. Feel free to make any amendments you like

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @GarethD. I'll make the changes to the code!